# Maven surefile plugin use

Tags: maven, plugins

Can any one please tell me the use of adding plugins in POM.xml file in Maven project. I tried working with creating new maven project and run it. In the site which reffered suggesting to add those two plugins. Can anyone please tell me the use ? Are these plugins important for running maven test ?

Comment: My POM.xml file looks like this.

Answer (score 0):

The Surefire plugin is an implicit plugin that will automatically run your tests in a `jar` project, i.e. `mvn test` binds to the `surefire:test` goal.  You don't need to add it to your POM unless you need to customize its configuration.

From the Surefire documentation:

> By default, the Surefire Plugin will automatically include all test
>   classes with the following wildcard patterns:
>
> "**/Test*.java" - includes all of its subdirectories and all Java
>   filenames that start with "Test". "**/*Test.java" - includes all of
>   its subdirectories and all Java filenames that end with "Test".
>   "**/*TestCase.java" - includes all of its subdirectories and all Java
>   filenames that end with "TestCase".

See this page for more details:

http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Built-in_Lifecycle_Bindings

http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html

http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html